# Ignore warning of statement with empty body

Tags: android-studio, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I want android studio does not flag as a warning when an if / else statement has the else empty.

this is an example:

[image]

I've been watching the preferences (/preferences/inspections) carefully, but I can not disable that warning.

Anyone know how to disable it? Thanks!

Comment: Just press alt + enter on that line, there will be an option showing disable inspection

Comment: This adds a `@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")` annotation to the method. Which does the actual disabling.

Comment: the Android tag is used for questions about Android, not Android Studio.

Comment: edited tags, thanks